# Why is FBX playback/import sooo slow

Tags: objects, armature, import, parent

### Still looking for some answers, reposting a question from blenderartists.

A while back we had our animations created in fbx. Playing these back now in blender is extremely slow. This doesn't seem normal at all. What's the workaround here, what does everyone do? We've tried opencollada importer/export. It was the artist who converted his source file in max to opencollada. Importing it for him worked fine, except in blender, it was all spaghetti monster once imported. Same thing with .x format. Everything default blender-wise seems broken. File is around 10MB, 1K polys, 700 verts, around 6000 frames of animation, 17 bones. Much obliged any info on this.

The files came from 3dsmax 2016, rig and animations were combined in one file. Other source viewers like open3mod and our custom engine using Assimp are able to load the model just fine (fast import and playback).

computer specs i5 4460, 16GB ram, gtx1060

Slow import and playback process:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1tXsoPBfBI

Comment: It's hard to tell about the slow import - there are a lot of keyframes which might be imported slowly. How are they imported into other programs? As to playback there isn't shown in the video what the time remapping for the frames you use. If they are default then probably that's how Blender treats these keyframes, maybe because of import/export.

Comment: I'm assuming imported models have no modifiers or other "automations" or optimizations, so everything is applied and all geometry is real which makes real time calculations slower